# Finding a Lyapunov function for modified quadratic form

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system, lyapunov-functions

I am trying to construct a Lyapunov function to show global asymptotic stability for a somewhat difficult system of equations. I was hoping people might have some suggests on what types of equations to try. The system of $n$ equations is given by:

$\dot{x} = MD(x)Rx-g(x)$

where $M$ is a symmetric matrix, $D(\vec{x})$ is a diagonal matrix with $\vec{x}$ on the diagonals, and $g(x)$ is a positive-definite function that is linear in $x$. If $M$ is the identity then this reduces to a standard quadratic form. But for $M$ otherwise, I am unable to control this system. You can assume that $M$ and $R$ are full rank, and that $M$ is positive definite.

I have been considering equations of the form:

$V(x) = \sum_i (Bx^*)_i \log (\frac{(Bx^*)_i}{(Bx)_i})$

such that:

$\dot{V}(x) = \sum_i \frac{(Bx^*)_i}{(Bx)_i} (B\dot{x})_i$

for some matrix $B$. For example, if $B$ is the identity matrix, then this gives:

$\dot{V}(x) = \sum_i \frac{x^*_i}{x_i} \dot{x}_i$

But I am starting to think that this general form is not an appropriate form to work with, as I cannot make any progress. My idea is that $B$ should be related to $M$ and/or $R$, but no luck.

Are there any obvious things I am missing or alternate Lyapunov functions that I should explore?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $g$ is a linear function in $x$? $g(x)=Gx$ or $g(x)=Gx+b$? It is more likely that you meant the first but I wanted clear all doubts.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it's generally something of the form $g(x)=Gx$ without a constant. For simplicity you can even just assume g(x)=x.

Comment: Did you linearize the system? Was the origin asymptotically stabel (AS)? If it is AS you can use the Lyapunov equation to come up with a quadratic Lapunov function.

Comment: If linearized as $\dot{x} = f(x)+Gx$, with f(x) the nonlinear term, then the $G$ does not have strictly negative eigenvalues --- a subset of them are exactly zero,  but otherwise none are positive.  The Jacobian is stable at the solution, but otherwise this is not the case for other values of $x$.

Comment: That is not a proper linearization of the equation. Your linearization should look like $$\Delta \dot{x} = A\Delta x.$$ If the eigenvalues of the $A$ matrix have strictly negative part then you can use Lyapunov's equation to determine a quadratic Lyapunov function.

Comment: So when I linearize around a point, $A$ in your notation becomes the Jacobian evaluated at that point. Indeed I can show that the solution is asymptotically stable, as the Jacobian at the solution is positive definite. But as far as I know, this is not helpful for constructing a general Lyapunov function to show global asymptotic stability, as the matrix A (i.e., the Jacobian) depends on the point about which I am linearizing. Am I missing something?

Comment: I added an answer because it was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have linearized the system at a particular equilibrium point, which is the origin of your nonlinear differential equation. Note, that we only investigate the stability of equilibrium point of a nonlinear system and not the system as a whole.

If the linearized system is given by

$$\Delta \dot{\boldsymbol{x}}=\boldsymbol{A}\Delta\boldsymbol{x}.$$

Determine all the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{A}$. By Lyapunov's indirect method we can distinguish three cases:

1. Case: All eigenvalues have a strictly negative real part. This implies that the equilibrium point of the nonlinear system is at least asymptotically stable.
2. Case: There exists at least one eigenvalue that has a strictly positive real part. This implies instability of the equilibrium point of the nonlinear system.
3. Case: All eigenvalues have a real part that is negative or equal to zero and there are eigenvalues with real part $0$. This is the indecisive case by the indirect method.

If you are in case one then you can invoke Lyapunov's converse theorems. This means that you can use the Lyapunov equation

$$\boldsymbol{PA}+\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{P}=-\boldsymbol{Q}$$

in which $\boldsymbol{P}$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix and $\boldsymbol{Q}$ is a positive definite matrix. Often $\boldsymbol{Q}$ is chosen as the identity matrix $\boldsymbol{I}$. By Lyapunov's converse theorem it is guaranteed that there exists a unique $\boldsymbol{P}$ such that

$$V(\Delta\boldsymbol{x})=\Delta\boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{P}\Delta\boldsymbol{x}$$

is a Lyapunov function of the nonlinear system in a neighbourhood of the equilibrium point (which is shifted to the origin).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I should have been more clear in my original post. I am looking to show global asymptotic stability, not just asymptotic stability of the solution. I have updated the wording in the main post to reflect this. Indeed, the solution is asymptotically stable, and I can just the Jacobian at the solution to show this, but I would like to show it converges to this solution for any starting condition.

Comment: In order to show global asymptotic stability (GAS). You can use an indirect procedure. You will have to show that there is only one equilibrium point of the equation (if there are multiple equilibrium points then it is impossible that the origin is GAS) and that there are no invariant sets (limit cycles) other then this equilibrium point. **And you should really add that you are looking for GAS in your question**.

Comment: Thanks, I already made the edit in my question. You raise a good point -- we currently cannot find a closed form solution for the equilibrium, so in fact we do not know that it is unique (apart from extensive simulations). But that being said, I not very familiar with how to go about showing there are no invariant sets. Do you know of any good resources to look into this further? (Thanks again for your continued help with this!)

Comment: For limit cycles, you can have a look at Nonlinear Dynamics by Steven Strogatz (he also has excellent youtube lectures on limit cycles) also Nonlinear Systems by Hassan Khalil covers some of these topics.